# Multiple meta tags for mobile optimisation?

Tags: mobile, meta-tags

For mobile optimization I've read that you should include all the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Are they all doing slightly different things or is there a hierarchy (e.g. the later tags overwriting the previous ones)?

As `MobileOptimized` includes a pixel width, is it possible to use `width=device-width` instead and is it advisable to do so? Will something like the iPhone scale to 320px or ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

Those tags seem to apply to Blackberry browsers and the older AvantGo browser in Palm Devices. The browsers found in iPhone (safari) and Android (including FireFox) use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) for determining which styles to apply to a web page. Since [Blackberry does support them, too](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp), I would say it is not necessary to use those meta tags and they should be considered obsolete.

Comment: I think your wrong. The last tag is needed to make my media queries be used on an iPhone. The iPhone by default acts as if its around 980px and scales the content down. The tag is needed to make the iPhone display smaller or its true resolution.